# Issue related to Magento Contact form

Tags: magento, form-submit, contact-form

We are having an issue in the contact for in a Magento store. When someone fills in the form **(Client)** on the website **(Person A),** the form gets submitted & a confirmation thank you message appears on the website thank you page. In the websites owners email ID **(Let's say Person-B, the supplier)** a thank you message is received stating **"Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon"** instead of the actual message from the sender.

**The client does not receive any message to their email at all.**

The, thank you for contacting us message must be sent to Person-A's email **(Client)** & the details filled by the Person A on website **(Client)** must be sent to the Person-B's email ID **(Supplier)**.

Can anyone suggest why this issue is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to chaeck that your email system is working or not.
Second thing you need to set email address in admin panel system -> configuration -> general -> contacts -> contact us -> enable setting
And  system -> configuration -> general -> contacts -> Email options -> set email address, sender name and template